# Using Alias in Conditional Constraint in GAMS

Tags: conditional-statements, alias, gams-math

I have a **set d** /NYCHI, NYBOS, NYDC, CHINY, BOSNY, DCNY / which is the set of trips between original points and destinations: NYC to Chicago, NYC to Boston, NYC to DC, and the trips of reverse directions.

I have a **variable b** which is the budget I need to prepare for the trips. I want to add a constraint that set the budget I need for the trip from NYC to Chicago is equal to the trip from Chicago to NYC; and so on (so basically the direction of the trip doesn't impact the budget). So I'm doing so in GAMS by using 2 parameters, origin and destination that are defined over set d, (NY is 1, Chicago is 2, Boston is 3, and DC is 4).

```
Set d /NYCHI, NYBOS, NYDC, CHINY, BOSNY, DCNY /;

Alias(d,dd);

Parameter
origin(d)  origin of trip
/NYCHI 1, NYBOS 1, NYDC 1, CHINY 2, BOSNY 3,  DCNY 4/
destination(d) destination of trip
/NYCHI 2, NYBOS 3, NYDC 4, CHINY 1, BOSNY 1, DCNY 1/;
```

So my constraint is:

```
constraint1(d)$(origin(d)=destination(dd) and origin(dd)=destination(dd)).. b(d) =e= b(dd);
```

But doing this I got error 149: Uncontrolled set entered as constant. What did I do wrong here? Any help is greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I do not exactly what you do, but about the error you get: `dd` is uncontrolled. Change your constraint like this to resolve it:

```
constraint1(d,dd)$(origin(d)=destination(dd) and origin(dd)=destination(dd)).. b(d) =e= b(dd);
```